# In geth, `eth.syncing` gives `false`

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

In geth, `eth.syncing` gives `false` but when I check the eth.blockNumber I get the latest block? And also all of my eth account has zero balance? how can I add balance or its just node not syncing yet or not syncing at all?